# Error in KeyAdapter part of this program

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, keylistener

Compilation and Execution is successful in this program . But When i type some characters the frame isn't showing those character within it. why ? what is the error.?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

class frameadapter extends WindowAdapter
{
    newframe newthis;

    public frameadapter(newframe n)
    {
        newthis=n;
    }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
        newthis.setVisible(false);
        System.exit(0);
    }

}


class keyadapter extends KeyAdapter
{
    newframe keythis;
    public keyadapter(newframe n1)
    {
        keythis=n1;
    }

    public void KeyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        keythis.keymsg+=ke.getKeyChar();
        System.out.println(keythis.keymsg);
        keythis.repaint();
    }   
}




public class newframe extends Frame implements MouseListener
{
    int mouseX;
    int mouseY;
    String keymsg="This is a Test";
    String msg="";
    public newframe()
    {
        addKeyListener(new keyadapter(this));
        addWindowListener(new frameadapter(this));
        addMouseListener(this);
        this.setSize(600,600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString(keymsg,100,100);
        g.drawString(msg, 500, 200);
    }


    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX=this.getX();
        mouseY=this.getY();
        msg="MOUSE CLICKED AT";
        repaint();
    }


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX=this.getX();
        mouseY=this.getY();
        msg="MOUSE PRESSED AT";
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX=this.getX();
        mouseY=this.getY();
        msg="MOUSE RELEASED AT";
        this.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX=this.getX();
        mouseY=this.getY();
        msg="MOUSE ENTERED AT";
        repaint();
    }


    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX=this.getX();
        mouseY=this.getY();
        msg="MOUSE EXITED AT";
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])    
    {
        newframe n=new newframe();
    }
}
```

The Error i think is in the Keyadapter class.But Unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `KeyListener` only responds to key events when the component it is registered to is focusable AND has keyboard focus
2. `Frame` is not focusable, from a key event standpoint, this makes it impossible for it to, but default, receive key event notification...

Unless you have some desperate need to do so, I would recommend against using `Frame` and instead, use a `JFrame` as your window, as AWT is 15+ years out of date and generally is not longer used.  Take a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details

Instead, start with a `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method be perform your custom painting there.  Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

Use the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to regsiter key actions against the panel.  This will allow you to define the focus level required for the panel to receive key event notification

Comment: yeah right.How did i forgot. thanks a ton Madprogrammer.